# Splicing a string and adding the same value for the index of the place of that value?

Tags: javascript, splice

I think I am pretty close to figuring this one out but was getting stumped.

I am trying to splice any string taken by a function and returning that string a value added for the place it holds in the string.

```
function addString();
```

When this function recieves a value like this:

```
let message = "abcd";
```

It will return that value like this:

```
console.log(addString(message));
"abbcccdddd"
```

Comment: What have you tried and what is or isn't working with that attempt?

Comment: "I think I am pretty close to figuring this one out" - Consider showing us just how close you are ;)

Comment: what if a message is `bacc` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could map the repeated value and join to a single string.

```js
let message = "abcd",
    result = [...message].map((c, i) => c.repeat(i + 1)).join('');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This works exactly as intended! I thought about mapping but was attempting a for each.

Answer (score 1):

While it would've been nice to see *your* attempts, try this out:

```js
function addString(str) {
    var output = "";
    str.split("").forEach(function(i, k) { //Split string up, loop through chars
        output += Array(k+2).join(str[k]);
    });
    return output;
}
    
   var myText = prompt("Enter a word.");
   alert(addString(myText));
```

You can create `n` occurrences of `c` using the method...

```
function repeatChar(n, c){
    return Array(n+1).join(c);
}
```

I've manipulated this logic to fit your question, in particular incrementing the array length by 2 instead of 1, so that index 0 is printed 1 time, and so-on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a concise solution :)

```js
const result = 'abcd'.replace(/./g, (c, i) => c.repeat(i+1));

document.write(result);
```

Note: arrow functions, `const` and `repeat` come with ES6.